# Keep image vertically centered/ fixed over moving slides?

Tags: css, slider, responsive

I have a slider (using bxslider) and I'd like to horizontally and vertically center a fixed image on top of the slider, so that the text stays and the slides, each with a different background image, beneath it move. I've tried the following, positioning the banner I want to stay in place, absolute to the parent section container, but this is not responsive. Is there a better, responsive way to keep the text vertically centered? Thanks, in advance:

```js
  $('#productslider').bxSlider({
   minSlides: 1,
   maxSlides: 1,
   pager: true,
   controls: false,
   auto: true,
   speed: 1000,
   pause: 7500
  });
```

```css
  #products {
    background-color: #FFFEE3;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative}

  #products .bx-wrapper {
    padding: 0; }

  #products .slide {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 360px; }

  #products .banner {
    position: absolute;
    height: 360px;
    padding: 5% 20%;
    z-index: 600;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center; }

  #chocbg {
    background-color: brown;
    }
  #vanbg {
      background-color: brown;
      }

  #cinbg {
      background-color: brown;
      }
```

```html
<section id="products">
 <div class="banner">
  <img src="img/products_intro.png">
 </div>
 <div id="productslider" class="intro">
  
  <div class="slide" id="chocbg">
   
  </div>
  <div class="slide" id="vanbg">
   
  </div>
  <div class="slide" id="cinbg">
  
  </div>
  
    </div>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely positioning the `banner` div on top of the slider will work. You can then use `display:flex` on that div to horizontally and vertically control it's contents in a responsive manner.

Here's a quick [example](http://codepen.io/BriceShatzer/pen/JKWQJP) I threw together showing what I'm talking about.

Comment: Your solution got me half the way there, however, I wanted the container for the sliders to be responsive and not set a fixed pixel height. In other words, I wanted the absolutely positioned image to dictate the size of the divs, even though it is outside of the div. I took your solution and combined it with creating dummy images inside each slide. This is a far from elegant solution, so if someone can suggest an alternative, I'd appreciate it. Here's the code-pen http://codepen.io/taikodesign/pen/zBwzyg